The blade is not perpendicular to the cut on a jigsaw: how to correct it?
I have a kind of run-of-the-mill lower end jigsaws:  a Black and Decker model as shown.  The blade is relatively new and i've verified it is straight/true.  On the jigsaw itself it is quite obvious that the blade is pointed at a slight angle. It's too difficult to see in the photos below, but it is pretty blatant when you stare it [down] in the face.  I'm not finding any adjustments to fix this issue. How is it done?
View from the bottom

View from the front

Here is a view of the bottom, I don't see much to work with here.

The tool is basically this model: Curve Control Black and Decker jigsaw
Update I have been able to quantify the issue a bit more carefully now.

The spring-loaded-clamp that holds the blade in [and shown in the red rectangle] is not true
The result is that the blade is pointing to the left [purple rectangle]
I did open the plate adjustment on the bottom of the jigsaw but that does not help with the problem here.

I'm not sure how to adjust that clamp.


the photos aren't making it super obvious, which way is the blade not straight? Is it not perpendicular to the glide surface of the shoe, or it is twisted compared to the centerline of the shoe?

@ratchetfreak Agreed: i am updating the question to help clarify

@ChrisH. They don't show up for a somewhat simpler reason than that : I just forgot to attach it!  D'oh.  Please take another look

the guide wheel does not adjust and your blade is bent,

Ah, yes. The curse of the run-of-the-mill lower end jigsaw. The guide is offset from the  holder. You take the blade out, it's straight. You put it back in and the guide  bends it.

@Jasen. The blade is straight, I measured it very carefully both sides. It lays completely flat on a flat surface.  The guide turns it when placed.

I wonder if the  guides start out misaligned or if they're prone to getting bent/loose.  Especially on a fairly weak tool that needs to be pushed a little even in thin material

@ChrisH This jigsaw has not had an easy life: I've been using it on demo and construction tasks for which it is maybe barely suited as well as cutting lots of flooring.  It has earned its keep and i can still use it for cutting sections of flooring where the ends are covered by the trim.

You can square up the sole plate on that model.  It still won't be perfect.
I have a similar one and by loosening the screw in the last photo (circled below) you can set the angle of the sole plate to the blade -- use a setsquare and rock it in the direction of the arrow.  However perfectly you do so, and however tightly you do it up the cut will never be perfectly square.  There's simply too much flex in the blade and probably a little play in the blade mounting as well.
It's likely to be acceptable for thin material, especially if you don't try to hard to turn, but if you're up to the limits of cutting depth it's quite noticeable.

I discovered this when trying to cut worktop for a kitchen.  I would have got away with it except I did most of the cut from the front edge, and then restarted from the back edge to minimise tear-out at the end.  The cuts sloped in different directions meaning the edging strip wouldn't go on properly.
Even after the edits, that's still the main adjustment.  On this, as on my B&D there are 2 screws at the top of the blade where it mounts.  They face forwards and look like socket heads on yours.  You can take them right out and clean that part of the blade mount to make sure everything sits nicely together.
Beyond the main adjustment, this little bit of maintenance, and checking your blade against a rule, there's not much you can do with a basic jigsaw (and little more with a fancier one).  I ended up buying a circular saw for 2 projects on thick oak because the squareness my jigsaw would get me would always have been unacceptable

Thanks for that info, I did adjust the sole plate. But please take a look at my question: I have updated with more info about the likely source of the problem which is the spring loaded clamp .  I don't know how to adjust it.

Generally, the detent is not adjustable. Consider replacing the tool.

A regular 7.25 inch circular saw is too unwieldy and risky to cut insets.  It's just not possible to use it without the risk of it running away and damaging the piece. It only takes one moment of inattention or a tiny bit of pinch and the tool will jump and cut into your piece. That's why I tried the jigsaw [and only after convincing myself I had learnt all there was to learn about the circular saw plunge cuts].  But it is truly not the tool for long deep precision cuts especially on harder materials.  I have a handheld 4.5 inch plunge-cut circular saw on order, let's see where that leads.

I agree.  I'd still use the jigsaw for insets but the ones I've done have always ended up with enough margin for an imperfect cut given their concealed edges (hobs/stovetops, sinks etc.). Anyway the rounded corners need a jigsaw, or a straight cut lined up perfectly to a drilled hole of the right diameter.  I considered a sabre saw/sawzall but never bought one.  Old question of mine for background

@ChrisH. The sabre saw is even [much..] worse for this. It is truly a demolition tool and keep it far away from new construction  let alone cabinetry.

@WestCoastProjects it felt like a tool that tries to do too much, TBH
